# Creating @XmlElement with same name tag 2 times

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshall an `XML` and the elements of a `node` are present in multiple class files, I need to to know if we can create `@XmlElement` tag 2 times with the same name and pass the same node to two different classes
I have the following XML:

```
<data>
    <properties>
        <id>ID123</id>
        <name>sss</name>
        <note>note</note>
    </properties>
</data>
```

root class file

```
@XmlRootElement(name="data")
public class Data {
    prop1 prop1;
    prop2 prop2;

    @XmlElement(name="properties")
    public prop1 getProp1(){
        return this.prop1;
    }
    public void setProp1(prop1 prop1){
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="properties")
    public prop2 getProp2(){
        return this.prop2;
    }
    public void setProp2(prop2 prop2){
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}

public class prop1{
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    //setters and getters for id node

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    //setters and getters for name node
}

public class prop2{
    private String note;

    @XmlElement(name="note")
    //setters and getters for note node
}
```

I have `id`, `name` in `prop1` class and `note` in `prop2` class. And all the elements are under one node.
Can I delcare Data class with `@XmlElement` tag two times with the same name and pass the same node to two different classes? I tried this but able to create an instance of only `prop1` class.

Looking for other options too to handle this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you really need to do it. Why cannot you have properties class from which you will get wrappers from Note part and Id/Name part.

One way, is to map the xml properites as it is in xml and used the marshaling/unmarshaling events to convert it to the your prop classes.

```
public class Properties {
@XMLElement
String id;
@XMLElement
String name;
@XMLElement
String note;
}

public class Data {
 @XMLElement
 Properties properties;
 @XMLTransient
 Prop1 prop1
 ....

 void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unm, Object parent) {
    prop1.id = properties.id;
    prop1.name = prperites.name;
    prop2.note = properties.note;
 };

 boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller mar) {  
    prop1 = new Prop1(properties.id,properties.name);
    prop2 = new Prop2(properties.note);
 };
}
```

So you need additional container (Properties) to store the value, but it will work with any jaxb implementation.

To avoid the container you could you XMLAdapter and jaxb extension that uses XMLTransforamtion to extract necessary parts from your xml node.
You can find the description with an example partially your case here:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/xmltransformation-going-beyond.html

But is based on eclipse implementation of jaxb and it requires a substantial amount of code.